# Melzi v3b firmware flash

Tags: firmware

I'm trying to flash the repetier Firmware to my Prusa i3 3D Printer, which uses Melzi 2.0 board. I uploaded it successfully 2 days ago with same settings but now is failing always.

```
@avrdude -p m1284p -b57600 -c arduino -P COM%x% -e -U flash:w:%filename%.hex
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9705 (probably m1284p)
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "newa.hex"
avrdude: input file newa.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (114266 bytes):
Writing |                                                    | 0% 0.00s
avrdude: stk500_paged_write(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x64 
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have had trouble before not using spacing between arguments. I think no spacing between `-b` and `57600` is causing the problem. Try

```
avrdude -p m1284p -b 57600 -c arduino -P COM%x% -e -U flash:w:%filename%.hex
```